# How to get two PreparedStatement objects for the same query string

Tags: java, cassandra

We have a use case where we need to have two separate PreparedStatement objects (one with RetryPolicy and the other without any retry policy) for the same query string.
And when we try to create two separate PreparedStatements, we see only one PreparedStatement getting retained (the previous PreparedStatement gets overridden by the last PreparedStatement). We looked at the code implementation and see that method `Cluster.addPrepared` is looking at some kind of MD5 hash for the query and it overrides the old PreparedStatement with the new PreparedStatement.

To overcome this behavior we are creating two separate queries (the second query has an extra space at the end compared to first query) to distinguish them so that we end up getting two prepared statements.

Eg: First query: `select * from test`, Second query: `"select * from test "`

Is there a better way of creating two separate PreparedStatements for the same query string as our use case demands it? To us it looks error prone.

We are using cassandra-drive-core-3.1.0-shaded.jar

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.*;
import com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException;
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy;
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.LoggingRetryPolicy;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CassandraHelper {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraHelper.class);
    private final String hostname;
    private final int port;
    private Cluster cluster;
    private Session session;

    private static final String selectStackoverflowCql =
            "SELECT key_part_one, key_part_two, data FROM test_keyspace.stackoverflow_composite WHERE key_part_one=? AND key_part_two=?";

    private static final String selectStackoverflowCqlWithSpace =
            "SELECT key_part_one, key_part_two, data FROM test_keyspace.stackoverflow_composite WHERE key_part_one=? AND key_part_two=? ";

    private PreparedStatement selectStackoverflowWithoutRetryPolicyStatement;
    private PreparedStatement selectStackoverflowStatement;
    private PreparedStatement selectStackoverflowStatementWithSpace;

    public CassandraHelper(String host, int port) {
        this.hostname = host;
        this.port = port;
        connect();
        install_schema();
        selectStackoverflowStatement = session.prepare(selectStackoverflowCql)
                .setRetryPolicy(new LoggingRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE));
        selectStackoverflowWithoutRetryPolicyStatement = session.prepare(selectStackoverflowCql);
        selectStackoverflowStatementWithSpace = session.prepare(selectStackoverflowCqlWithSpace)
                .setRetryPolicy(new LoggingRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE));
    }

    public void connect() {
        int maxRetries = 2;
        for (int numReties = 0; numReties < maxRetries; numReties += 1) {
            log.info("Connecting (attempt {})...", numReties);
            try {
                cluster = buildCluster();
                session = cluster.connect();
                log.info("Created session");
                ResultSet rs = session.execute("select release_version from system.local");
                Row row = rs.one();
                log.info("Version: {}", row.getString("release_version"));
                return;
            } catch (NoHostAvailableException ex) { // if we get this exception, wait for Cassandra to become available
                log.info("Got NoHostAvailableException");
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to connect to Cassandra cluster");
    }

    private Cluster buildCluster() {

        if (this.cluster == null || this.cluster.isClosed()) {
            this.cluster = Cluster.builder()
                    .withMaxSchemaAgreementWaitSeconds(20)
                    .addContactPointsWithPorts(Lists.newArrayList(new InetSocketAddress(this.hostname, this.port)))
                    .withoutJMXReporting().build();
            this.cluster.init();
            log.info("Built cluster");
            cluster.getConfiguration().getQueryOptions().setDefaultIdempotence(true);
        }
        return cluster;
    }

    public PreparedStatement getSelectStackoverflowStatementWithSpace() {
        return selectStackoverflowStatementWithSpace;
    }

    public PreparedStatement getSelectStackoverflowWithoutRetryPolicyStatement() {
        return selectStackoverflowWithoutRetryPolicyStatement;
    }

    public PreparedStatement getSelectStackoverflowStatement() {
        return selectStackoverflowStatement;
    }


    private void install_schema() {
        List<String> creationCqls = Lists.newArrayList(
                "CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS test_keyspace WITH replication = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 }",
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_keyspace.stackoverflow_composite (key_part_one text, key_part_two int, data text, PRIMARY KEY(key_part_one, key_part_two))");
        Stream<String> stream = creationCqls.stream();
        stream.forEach(cql -> {
            if (!executeSchemaChange(cql)) {
                log.info("Schema agreement timeout attempting to execute {}. (This is not a problem as we will wait for schema agreement in the verification step.", cql);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean executeSchemaChange(String cql) {
        ResultSet rs = session.execute(cql);
        return rs.getExecutionInfo().isSchemaInAgreement();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CassandraHelper ch = new CassandraHelper("localhost", 32769);
        assert (ch.getSelectStackoverflowWithoutRetryPolicyStatement() == ch.getSelectStackoverflowStatement());
        assert (ch.getSelectStackoverflowStatementWithSpace() != ch.getSelectStackoverflowStatement());
        System.out.println("Statement without Retry Statement: " + ch.getSelectStackoverflowWithoutRetryPolicyStatement());
        System.out.println("Statement with Retry and query not having space: " + ch.getSelectStackoverflowStatement());
        System.out.println("Statement with Retry and query with space: " + ch.getSelectStackoverflowStatementWithSpace());
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @mentallurg I added the code for your reference